# CakePHP: Check if user is already logged in

Tags: session, cakephp

I'm trying to forbid multiple logins by the same user at the same time to my CakePHP (1.2) driven site. However, that's not as easy as I thought since I have no idea how to get the information if a user is already logged in or not.

I'm using Cake's Auth-component to authenticate users. The sessions are handled by the php installation and php stores the session data in files. So I guess it is not possible to access the session data from a controller (for, of course, these files aren't saved in the webroot). I thought about checking if a user is logged in or not by using a special database field but there is no way to find out if a user is logged out or not if he doesn't use the logout-method but simply closes his browser and so ends the session.

Can anyone think of another way to manage that? I don't need to know all data about every logged in user. The only thing I need to know is if the given username is logged in at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* CakePHP will have this behaviour automatically if you set `Security.level` to `high` in your core config file, as it regenerates the session ID each time.

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'high');
```

Alternatively, the logic behind it is that you could save a hash of the users IP/User Agent in the user table when they login, and if a computer with a different hash to the one you have saved tries to do something, logout the user. This way only the latest user will work.

Comment: Hehe, beat me to it. When set to high, CakePHP already checks the user agent (it hashes it and stores it in the session file so no need for a database field). Some users are behind proxy servers that use a pool of public IPs, so I wouldn't check for changes in IP.

Comment: That sounds quite good. But the regeneration of the session ID seems to have the side effect that logged in users are logged out randomly. At least that does not happen when the security.level is set to 'medium'. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you use 'high' the timeout is greatly reduced (*10 as sooposed to *100), maybe try increasing the Session.timeout config var.

Comment: I set Session.timeout is set to 4320. That should be enough by far (43200s = 12h).

Comment: security.level high is not compatible with Ajax. If you have any Ajax calls you won't be able to use the highest level.

Comment: I have searched for an answer like that but found only descriptions of the  problem without solutions. The site indeed uses a lot of AJAX. Thank you.

Comment: In that case try implementing the second paragraph of my answer yourself, just take the user-agent at login and then check each request in `beforeFilter()`

Comment: But is the user agent really appropriate for that? It does not contain any information that is really unique for some user. Couldn't I save the session id instead?

Comment: Yeah either/or, useragent was just an example.